# IndexOutOfBoundsException on arraylist java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm looking for the equivalent word in the database by the ContextQuery method, and when a equivalent word is null the program must try to use the next index from words and add it up to the current to make it a two word, if the two word is still null the program will make it a three word looking for the next 2 value, the equivalent is now being printed in console but i have the error IndexOutOfBoundsExpection after running

```
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
        temp = QueryWithContext.query(words.get(i));
            if((temp == null || temp.isEmpty()) && words.size() >= i+1)
            {
            QueryWithContext.query(words.get(i)+" "+words.get(i+1));
            temp = QueryWithContext.query(words.get(i)+" "+words.get(i+1));
            System.out.println("1st if");
                if((temp == null || temp.isEmpty()) && words.size() >= i+2)
                    {
                    temp = QueryWithContext.query(words.get(i)+" "+words.get(i+1)+" "+words.get(i+2));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp = words.get(i);
                    }

            }



            System.out.println(temp);
```

Comment: Then i is too large. Step through the code in the debugger.

Comment: What about `i`? From where do you get it and how do you update it?

Comment: Post edited, forgot to include the for loop

Answer (score 2):

```
if((temp == null || temp.isEmpty()) && words.size() >= i+1)
```

must be

```
if((temp == null || temp.isEmpty()) && words.size() > i+1)
```

otherwise

```
words.get(i+1)
```

throws the IndexOutOfBoundsExpection.

Comment: Got it thanks, and how can i move to the next for loop after it passes by the if condition

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely in this line: `temp = QueryWithContext.query(words.get(i)+" "+words.get(i+1)+" "+words.get(i+2));`. You are looping until `i` is less than the size of `words`, so `i` will range from 0 to `n - 1`.

The problem is that in your code, you keep going till `i + 2` (and previously, `i + 1`). This is what is most likely causing your error. To fix this, see if you can do the following: `for (int i = 0; i < (words.size() - 2); i++){`

Alternatively, do as @Uli recommends.